# Spark and Mesos: No credentials provided

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, pyspark, mesos

I want to run a spark example on my mesos master node and it gaves me this problem. It just 'stop' here without showing any results or exceptions.

> I0908 18:38:01.636055  9044 sched.cpp:226] Version: 1.0.1 I0908
>   18:38:01.636485 28512 sched.cpp:330] New master detected at
>   master@124.216.0.14:5050 I0908 18:38:01.636642 28512 sched.cpp:341] No
>   credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication

Comment: What can you see in Master logs?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's not enough info there to debug, unfortunately.

> New master detected at master@124.216.0.14:5050

This is the normal debug message during the Spark startup process or after Mesos master re-election. It discovered a Mesos master it didn't know about and acted accordingly.

> No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication

This line is just a control flow debug message, a red herring that looks like an error but is really harmless in most cases.

It indicates that Mesos authentication is being skipped when registering with as a framework. Optional framework/service authentication was added for compatibility with the new Mesosphere Enterprise DC/OS which allows strict, permissive, or disabled modes of security when using the Mesos API. If you're using open source DC/OS or just plain Mesos, it's probably functioning in disabled security mode, because it doesn't have the authorization or service account infrastructure.